# What the equivalent BandwidthMeter(ExoPlayer, Android) in AVPlayer (apple)

Tags: avplayer, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, avplayeritem

I have experience with ExoPlayer and I am starting to use AVPlayer for iOS applications.

I am wondering - How can I get the current download rate (estimation)?

**It means what the equivalent BandwidthMeter in AVPlayer?**